# Any API to get services level performance metrics

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes

We like to know if there is a way to get the service level monitoring parameters like ( how many request / sec, latency / request , etc...) from the Kubernetes Service?.
I understand that if Kubernetes service is created with type LoadBalancer, then we can leverage the cloud provider interfaces for those metrics; However I like to know if there is any provision to get the above said metrics at service level or container level without any latency.?.

Answer (score 2):

Not presently. This is being tracked in [issue 9215](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9125). As is pointed out in the issue, use of iptables makes this non-trivial.